# Passing Uiimages to view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

So I have a custom camera called Paparazzo and the images taken from the camera are stored in a custom array called ImageSource. Now i declared that I would pass ImageSource from the camera view controller to my second view controller, but what I realized where that my images where coming up nil on the second view controller. How can I pass all the images from Photos which is declared an ImageSource through a segue. That is my problem. Here is my code.

```
private var photos = [ImageSource]()

@IBAction private func showMediaPicker() {
    var theme = PaparazzoUITheme()
    theme.shutterButtonColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    let assemblyFactory = Paparazzo.AssemblyFactory(theme: theme)
    let assembly = assemblyFactory.mediaPickerAssembly()
    let mediaPickerController = assembly.module(
        items: [],
        selectedItem: nil,
        maxItemsCount: 20,
        cropEnabled: true,
        cropCanvasSize: CGSize(width: 1280, height: 960),
        configuration: { [weak self] module in
            weak var module = module

            module?.setContinueButtonTitle("Done")

            module?.onFinish = { mediaPickerItems in
                // storing picked photos in instance var and updating UI
                self?.photos = mediaPickerItems.map { $0.image }
                self?.updateUI()
                self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowNow", sender: self?.photos)
            }
            module?.onCancel = {
                module?.dismissModule()
            }
        }
    )

    navigationController?.pushViewController(mediaPickerController, animated: true)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ShowNow") {
        if let pivc: view2ViewController? = segue.destination as? view2ViewController,
            let images = sender as? [UIImage] {
            pivc?.image2 = images
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: replace  let images = sender as? [UIImage] {
            pivc?.image2 = images
        }    by pivc?.image2 = photos

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass UIImage through save the image in [NSUserDefault standardUserDefault] setobject:image  valueforkey:@"img" ] and get it by [NSUserDefault standardUserDefault] valueforkey:@"img" ] or You can pass it by making global variable of UIImage and passes to the another viewcontroller.

Use this code for save image For the PNG:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"img"];
```

Use this code for save image For the JPEG:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"img"];
```

and get it back by using this code

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"img"]; UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Can you show me an example please I'm not following what your saying.

Comment: Use this code for save image
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"img"];

and get it back by using this code
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"img"];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

Comment: Could you please put it in a code form so I can read it clearly

Comment: Thank you I will try it and let you know how it is

Comment: I know I'm at work right now and will get back home at 12:30. So I will check then and if it's right I will mark it

Comment: Passing data between two view controllers using `UserDefaults` isn't the good way : this class is mostly made for saving settings and restore it at App Launch, as stated in https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults  . Use `prepareForSegue` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your first ViewController has the an array with ImageSource's inside.
Your destination ViewController should have similar array (ex.: `var passedPhotos: [ImageSource]?`).

Your `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any)` method in first VC should look like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier") {
        if let secondVC: YourSecondViewController? = segue.destination as? YourSecondViewController,
            if let photosToPass = photos {
                secondVC?.passedPhotos = photosToPass 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make an array in secondVC like

```
 var arrImages =  Array()
```

Then do this stuff in your currentVC

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "ShowNow") {
             let pivc: view2ViewController? = segue.destination as? view2ViewController

                pivc?.arrImages = images
// here images is the array of images

        }
    }
```

Comment: What about photos. I'm accessing the images from imagesource. All the images taken from the camera are automatically stored in imagesource

Comment: You said you are storing the images in a custom array ImageSource.So you can get it from there and then can pass to the next VC.

Comment: I got this error "Could not cast value of type 'ImageSource.PHAssetImageSource' (0x10c3d87c8) to 'UIImage' (0x10e8100b0)."

Comment: I accessed the images in arrImages in here as "LIHSlider(images: arrImages as! [UIImage])"